# Conditional includes in Qt project file / qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

I am creating a brand new project (a daemon) and I would like to minimize its dependencies and work.

One of its dependencies, used in other projects, does some logging using another library dependency. I don't want the logging in my daemon.

Even more... the logger library is a submodule... I don't even want to bring that submodule in for the daemon project.

I am thinking of setting the dependencies based on a definition in the project... something like:

> daemon.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = Dependency \
          MyDaemon
CONFIG += ordered
DEFINES += NO_LOGGING
```

> Dependency.pro

```
TEMPLATE = lib

NO_LOGGING {
} else {
LIBS += -L$$OUT_PWD/../Logger/ -lLogger
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../Logger
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../Logger
}
```

> dependency.cpp

```
#ifdef NO_LOGGING
// Redefine log function as a no-op
#else
#include "Logger.h"
#endif
```

Sounds good ? It did to me - but it doesn't work.

It seems that I cannot pass defines from the container to the inner projects...

Is there any way to set this up ?

The alternative is to just contend with a small amount of logging...

Linux... embedded... Qt 4.7

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662644/qt-passing-variables-to-subprojects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, you create an include file, and then use it in all your projects, like this:

> mydemon.pri

```
features = logging other_feature # any name will do
```

> mydemon.pro

```
include(mydemon.pri)
...
contains(features, logging) {
    # implement it here
} else {
    DEFINES += NO_LOGGING
}
```

> dependency.pro

```
include(../mydemon/mydemon.pri, demon)
...
contains(demon.features, logging) {
    # use logging
} else {
    # no logging available
}
```